# RecyclerView not updating items with position

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview

I am loading items into a recyclerview from the server using JSON, maintaining an Adapter class to set data by hashmap method. I am using pagination for the recyclerView. Each page contains 10 items and the page increments after 10 items are reached.

The issue is that, after loaded, it's not refreshing when the users click the items.

HomeClass is a launcher activity:

```
public class HomeClass  extends AppCompatActivity {

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      sendID(url);
    }

      public void sendID(final String url){
        if (progress == null) {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progress.show();
        }
        Constant.Home_Posts.clear();
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
           ///pagecount is 1 in HomeClass by default
               JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(arg0);

          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 map.put(key,value);
                Constant.Home_Posts.add(map);
                }
             }
                if (progress!=null) {
                  if (progress.isShowing()) {
                     progress.dismiss();
                     progress = null;
               Intent intent = new Intent(HomeClass.this, Home.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                     finish();
                  }
        }
```

The second class, Home, only contais onBindViewHolder

```
       public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       }

      private void getPostCount(final String URl) {
        if (progress == null) {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progress.show();
        }
         new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                viewposition = viewposition + 10;
                getPostUrl = "url+userid="+ userID+ "&page="+ page_count;

           //pagecount is 2 in 'Home' by default and then icrements
           JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(arg0);

               HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 map.put(key,value);
                Constant.Home_Posts.add(map);
                     '
                     '
                }
             }
            }
            page_count++;
```

Adapter Class:

```
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder,final int i) {
            if (Constant.Home_Posts.size() - 1 == i) {
                Constant.Home_Posts.clear();
                getPostCount("url+ userID + "&page=" + page_count);
            }

         //set value using hashmap method from server
        viewHolder.imgComment.setText(value) //with integer values


       //OmCLick to update datas from user    
       viewHolder.imgComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                //get layout view by LayoutIflater and load data from server

                // create alert dialog
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
               //user can comment anyhting,if success comment value in count 
               //should increment or comments should not change                 

                 sendComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {

                            if (commentStatus == 0) {
                            } else {
                              alertDialog.cancel();


           String putLikesValue=(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(
                Constant.Home_Posts.get(i).get("comments_count"))+1));

           viewHolder.txtComment.setText(putLikesValue+"Comments");

                 notifyDataSetChanged();
                     notifyItemChanged(i);
                 });
               }
```

The result is like,
the old items are listing with the updated item (newly inserted item).

How do I insert the item with position properly?

Comment: I am not getting that what you're trying to do

Comment: The datas are loading 10 items/page. If i increment page in API only i can load remaining data in recyclerView (like pagination), This is working good. After loaded items in RecylerView, When user clicks getting layout with EditText for comment . The content wil update to server, if response is success i need to increment count otherwise dismiss layout view. The issue is i tried to update count like inserting but the count is inserting as new item, Even if i set with position when do onScroll it is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Hello use this for load all data.

```
 public FriendsAdapterSwipe(List<FriendListModel> alFriendListModel,RecyclerView recyclerView,Context context)
 {
    this.alFriendListModel = alFriendListModel;
    this.context=context;

    if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
    if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.raw_friends_swipe, parent, false);
        vh = new CustomViewHolder(itemView);
    } else
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.progressbar_item, parent, false);
        vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
    }
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if (holder instanceof CustomViewHolder)
    {
        Typeface AvenirNextRegular = Fonts.AvenirNextRegular(context);
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        FriendListModel model = alFriendListModel.get(position);
        ((CustomViewHolder) holder).txtUname.setText(model.getFullName());
        ((CustomViewHolder) holder).txtUname.setTypeface(AvenirNextRegular);

        if (alFriendListModel.get(position).getIsImageAvaible().equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
        {
            Glide.clear(((CustomViewHolder) holder).imgProfile);
            Glide.with(context).load(WebField.PROFILE_URL + alFriendListModel.get(position).getFriendId()
                    + "_small.png").asBitmap()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_pic).skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).
                    fitCenter().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(((CustomViewHolder) holder).imgProfile)
            {
                @Override
                protected void setResource(Bitmap resource)
                {
                    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), resource);
                    ((CustomViewHolder) holder).imgProfile.setImageDrawable(d);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ((CustomViewHolder) holder).imgProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_pic);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return alFriendListModel.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return alFriendListModel.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
}

public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
    void onLoadMore();
}

public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
    this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
}

public static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView txtUname;
    CircularImageView imgProfile;;

    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtUname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
        imgProfile = (CircularImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgProfile);
    }
}

public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }
}
public void setLoaded() {
    loading = false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for post, This looks like a get, set method, i have already tried this, It din't update the item in recyclerview.

Comment: type doesn't matter,I have items like user can post  images/videos and other users can comment it..i am loading all the posts from server..if any user comments for the post, it will connect to server if success and the comment item alone should update the count(+1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use loader for set data based on page.

```
 public EventAdapter(final List<EventsModel> myDataSet, RecyclerView recyclerView, Context context) {
    mDataset = myDataSet;
    this.context = context;

    if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);


                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    // End has been reached
                    // Do something
                    if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mDataset.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;


    if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {


        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.raw_eventlist, parent, false);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(EventFragment.myOnClickListener);

        vh = new TextViewHolder(itemView);

    } else {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.progressbar_item, parent, false);
        vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
    }
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof TextViewHolder) {

        Typeface AvenirNextRegular = Fonts.AvenirNextRegular(context);
        ((TextViewHolder) holder).txtEventName.setTypeface(AvenirNextRegular);
        ((TextViewHolder) holder).txtEventDescription.setTypeface(AvenirNextRegular);
        ((TextViewHolder) holder).txtDate.setTypeface(AvenirNextRegular);
        ((TextViewHolder) holder).txtTime.setTypeface(AvenirNextRegular);

        ((TextViewHolder) holder).txtEventName.setText(mDataset.get(position).getStrEventName());
        ((TextViewHolder) holder).txtEventDescription.setText(mDataset.get(position).getStrDescription());
        ((TextViewHolder) holder).txtDate.setText(mDataset.get(position).getStrStartDate());
        ((TextViewHolder) holder).txtTime.setText(mDataset.get(position).getStrStartTime());


        final RecyclerView.ViewHolder tempHolder = holder;
        String eventId = mDataset.get(position).getStrEventId();


            if (mDataset.get(position).getIsImageAvailable().equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            {
                Glide.clear(((TextViewHolder) holder).imgProfile);
                Glide.with(context).load(WebField.EVENT_URL + eventId + "_small.png").asBitmap()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.event_img).skipMemoryCache(true).
                        diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).fitCenter()
                        .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(((TextViewHolder) holder).imgProfile) {
                            @Override
                            protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {

                                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), resource);
                                ((TextViewHolder) tempHolder).imgProfile.setImageDrawable(d);
                            }

                        });
            }
            else
            {
                ((TextViewHolder) holder).imgProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.event_img);
            }
    }
}

public void setLoaded() {
    loading = false;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
    this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
}

public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
    void onLoadMore();
}

public static class TextViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CircularImageView imgProfile;
    TextView txtEventName;
    TextView txtEventDescription;
    TextView txtDate;
    TextView txtTime;
    ImageView btnNext;

    public TextViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.imgProfile = (CircularImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgProfile);
        this.txtEventName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtEventName);
        this.txtEventDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtEventDescription);
        this.txtDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        this.txtTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
        this.btnNext = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    }
}

public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable time, Sachin. I have also tried to load the page to update the comment item, but retain to scrolled page is difficult..for example first page and second page is getting retained but the pages 3 and after that are not loading like where left off. Thats'y i chose to inflate the comment box as layout view..hope i explained what the issues is exaclty now

Comment: I have not get the answer that i expected. will accept at-least when i get the expected answer